# Code snippets goes blank if I click on them

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

I've recently noticed that if I click on the code snippets (even for scrolling horizontally), the code itslef goes blank.

[image: Blank snippet code]

I'm actually accessing StackOverflow through Mozilla Firefox 72.0.2 (64-bit) Win10 x64.

Seems like a bug to me. Hope this helps fixing it. I'm actually logged in

Comment: @rene I'm sorry, it is. I'm going to edit the question adding that missed details.

Comment: I can't repro on Chrome so if anything is is contained to Firefox. You don't have any userscripts running?

Comment: @rene No, in fact I have no extensions running on Firefox. Any config/log I could provide to ease reproducing the issue? I've noticed the address bar is completely blank, constantly. I can't see what I'm typing there. I could just see what I'm typing if I open an incognito window, but even there it's still happening

Comment: well, that sounds very weird, the blank address bar I mean. Can you repro in IE11 or Edge?

Comment: No repro Firefox 72.0.2 (64 bit) or 52.9.1 ESR (32 bit).

Comment: @rene Confirmed it's just happening on Mozilla Firefox. Not even on IE11.592, Edge or Chrome :(

Comment: At least that means your PC and (local) network are not part of the problem....

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. also on an Windows OS?

Comment: Sorry, yes. The first on Windows 10*64, the second on XP*32. @rene

Comment: @rene I'm not really sure how Firefox's fault is, but I don't want to fully close it yet so it might get fixed "by rebooting it". Any additional info I could provide I will do it gladly

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. *XP* ... respect ...

Comment: When it happens, I'd right click and Inspect the code area to see what's there. Because the horizontal scroll bars are still there, it sounds like the content isn't going away, it's just hidden for some reason, see if the CSS is being applied? *I've noticed the address bar is completely blank, constantly* I'd bet it's just that your FF installation has problems. I'd restart, completely uninstall, and reinstall, then see if the problem still exists

Comment: Following @CertainPerformance I've just inspected the element and the behaviour is even more interesting. I've just recorded another gif but it just weighs too much (3,41MB) so I've manually uploaded it to imgur: https://imgur.com/TD940ac